# how run a sh file and export variable in c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, export

Im trying to read an exported variable in c but i cant, there are two scenarios.

**A)**

1) i have a sh file like:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 3s ./program
export OUT=$?
```

2) then i run: `. file.sh`

3) and when i read the var in c with:

`getenv("OUT")` yes, i read it.

**B)**

1. in c: `system("/bin/bash -c '. PathOfFile/file.sh'");`
2. `getenv("OUT")` . i cant access to OUT

i need run the sh file in c and read the var also in c

thanks

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many would refuse to admit it, but most of *us* have the exact same question just after discovering the environment variables. Today, it's seems "so evident" but at that time it wasn't easy. So I will try to explain things the most clearly and simply as I can.

First, as someone else said before, you must know the concept of *process*. I won't go into the details, but each time you launch an executable program, you create a new process. In Unix/Linux world, process are organized in strict *tree hierarchy*. That is all process having one unique ultimate ancestor called `init`. `init`has launched some processes on startup. In their turn those processes have launched others, and so on, down until that *shell* where you launch yourself some other processes. So:

- When you launch your compiled program, you create a new process
  (having your current shell as father).
- When you call `system` to
  execute a script you create a new process `sh` (having the host
  program as father)
- When your shell script call an external
  program/command it creates a new process (having the script's
  execution shell as parent)

As you understand, the hierarchy might go deep fast. If you have the command `pstree` on your system, you might call it from a shell to display the current process hierarchy. This might help you to get grasp on it.

One key feature is that any process has an *environment* -- constituted by the set of its environment variables and their corresponding values.

And here is the big secret: when a process launch an other process, **the new process inherit a *copy* of the environment of its father**. Since it is a copy, **the *child process* can do what it want with its own environment, this won't alter it's father environments**. Nor its grand-father, nor its grand-grand-father, nor...)

---

So the moral of the story is, **a process cannot use environment variables to communicate with any of its ancestors**.

As this is your need, you would have to rely to an other strategy:

- You might want to communicate through [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (`stdout`) as a process can *read* its child's *output*. Or (this is in fact a variation) use a [*named pipe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).
- If you want something a little bit more elaborated, modern systems have a bunch of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), like [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). But those are not really suitable to communicate with a *shell script*.
- Finally, you might rely on (more or less) dedicated systems: [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) (RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, ...), shared cache ([*memcached*](http://memcached.org/), ...), database, ... But those are probably way too much heavy weighted given your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The environment in POSIX is inherited by new processes (created by fork) aka child processes.  But when you change the environment in a child process and that process ends there is nothing which saves the environment or causes the parent process to get any information other than the exit code of the child process.  If you want to save something from the child process you have to make that happen with some form of IPC, from saving it in a file to using sockets or memcached.

Answer (score 1):

In case 'B' sh file will run in new process.

To make it more clear what you can do is:

1. Open two terminal windows.
2. Export your variable in one window.
3. Now run your c program in another window.

You'll find that you can not access that variable in second terminal window.In case 'A' you were being able to access the variable because you were running your c program from same terminal window(which make your c program a child process of terminal session).All child process inherit environment variables from parent.As others mentioned that you can see complete process tree using **pstree** command and you will find **init** as root of the tree.

What you can do is make another c file which contains:

system("/bin/bash -c '. PathOfFile/file.sh'");

and in file.sh first export your variable and then run actual c file.

Another way is to use IPC.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the concept of process. `system("/bin/bash -c '. PathOfFile/file.sh'");` will create a new process for you to run your file.sh, and the `OUT` environment variable is declared in your file.sh, in other word, it exists in the context of the new process. However, your just can't get the environment variable in your C code (which call `system` function), because it's totally different process context. Of course you can still use IPC methods to get this environment variable if you want.